# I can't find the corner cases

Tags: python, algorithm

The problem specification is in https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmwxcsp3lie0x3n/437.pdf?dl=0

My solution is in http://ideone.com/3JsFCq

```
name = raw_input()
D = int(raw_input()) #degree of separation
N = int(raw_input()) #number of links
M = int(raw_input()) #book users

users = {}
books = {}

def build_edges(user1, user2):
    if user1 not in users:
        users[user1] = set([user2, ])
    else:
        users[user1].add(user2)

for i in xrange(N):
    nw = raw_input()
    us = nw.split('|')
    build_edges(us[0], us[1])
    build_edges(us[1], us[0])

def build_booklist(user1, book):
    if user1 not in books:
        users[user1] = []
    else:
        users[user1].append(user2)

for i in xrange(M):
    bk = raw_input().split('|')
    books[bk[0]] = []
    for book in bk[1:]:
        books[bk[0]].append(book)

rec = []
depth = [0,]

def bfs(graph, start):
    visited, queue = set(), [start]
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.pop(0)
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            for book in books[vertex]:
                if book not in books[start]:
                    rec.append(book)
            queue.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
        depth[0] += 1
        if depth[0] > D:
            return
    return visited 

bfs(users, name)
print len(rec)
```

I couldn't find the corner cases.

It passes the example case, but it doesn't pass some others.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are increasing the `depth` every time you process a vertex. Instead you need to store a depth for every vertex, and stop when you encounter a vertex with a `depth` larger that the given.

For example, if Alice has two friends, Bob and Carl, then as you process Alice, you will set depth to 1. Then as you process Bob, you will set it to two, and stop, before you process Carl, who is within distance one from Alice. Instead, you should set Alice's depth to 0, then as you add Bob and Carl to the queue, set their depths to 1, and process them. As you process them, you add their friends, whom you have not seen yet, with depth 2, and as soon as you encounter any of them in the main loop (pop from the queue), you stop.

UPDATE: also, add the first vertex to the visited set, when you initialize it. Otherwise you will process it as a vertex with depth two (you will add Alice's friend Bob with depth 1, and then Alice as Bob's friend with distance two). It doesn't hurt in this particular problem, but might be a problem if you make a similar mistake in a solution for some other BFS problem.